# How can I disable the side buttons on my Mighty Mouse in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, mouse

I'm currently stuck with using an Apple Mighty Mouse I had laying around on my Vista (64-bit) workstation right now. I *always* accidentally press its left side button with my thumb, and, of course, it's bound by default to go back in web pages, and do other annoying things.

I have checked the mouse configuration settings in the Control Panel, and there isn't any settings to do with button configuration. Where should I be looking, or what software do I need to install to be able to disable the side buttons on my mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

I found that linked off:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7296315

Sounds like you can use that software to disable the 4th button. He even has 64 and 32bit versions.

Comment: Works well in Windows 7 too

Answer (score 0):

X-Mouse Button Control is a windows application to remap your mouse buttons.
This software is designed and written for Microsoft Windows XP/2003 x64 Edition but I have also, from version 1.5, built a 32bit version.

You are able to provide an application specific mappings, which means one application can use the mouse differently from another. This is useful for games which do not inherently support the extended mouse buttons, because you can map keys to each button.

http://wakoopa.com/software/xmousebuttoncontrol-application